# How to redirect to user organic group on login

Tags: users, organic-groups

I am trying to redirect the user to a page for which he is an organic user, and I want this redirect to happen after user login.

I am trying to use the `hook_user_login()` to make this redirect. However, I have found that when I inspect the `$user` object when it hits that hook, the `$user->og_user_node` field is empty. When I look at the user's edit screen (or when I inspect it with devel), it does have associated groups.

How can I retrieve a user's groups to make this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using code to do this you should be able to use [og_get_groups_by_user](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_get_groups_by_user/7) to return that information. This will return all groups of either the active user or the $account object that you pass to the function.

You can also use Rules to do this without code pretty easily. There is a rule export on this [page](https://groups.drupal.org/node/213088) to help get started if you want to go that way.

Just to add: the place you are looking for the og group should be under og_membership I think, not og_user_nodes but that's off the top of my head :)